# Can not register token with GCM

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I copy some google example for GCM(https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExample/)

```
// [START_EXCLUDE]
_registrationKey = @"onRegistrationCompleted";
_messageKey = @"onMessageReceived";
// Configure the Google context: parses the GoogleService-Info.plist, and initializes
// the services that have entries in the file
NSError* configureError;
[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];
NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);
_gcmSenderID = [[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configuration] gcmSenderID];
// Register for remote notifications
UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
// [END register_for_remote_notifications]
// [START start_gcm_service]
GCMConfig *gcmConfig = [GCMConfig defaultConfig];
gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self;
[[GCMService sharedInstance] startWithConfig:gcmConfig];
// [END start_gcm_service]
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
// Handler for registration token request
_registrationHandler = ^(NSString *registrationToken, NSError *error){
    if (registrationToken != nil) {
        weakSelf.registrationToken = registrationToken;
        NSLog(@"Registration Token: %@", registrationToken);
        [weakSelf subscribeToTopic];
        NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"registrationToken":registrationToken};
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:weakSelf.registrationKey
                                                            object:nil
                                                          userInfo:userInfo];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Registration to GCM failed with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"error":error.localizedDescription};
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:weakSelf.registrationKey
                                                            object:nil
                                                          userInfo:userInfo];
    }
};
```

it's launchOptions code for GCM.
but when i run it, catch some error, like this:
[image]

Comment: You probably have not installed the GCM dependency. You can install it via cocoapods, you can read [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client#set_up_your_cocoapods_dependencies) for more details.

Comment: @ztan I also use pod install to add GCM. add "pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'" to Podfile, and run command "pod install"

Comment: @smallg Try updating your cocoapod version. This seems like a bug in CocoaPods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i am already fixed it. modify Other Link Flag value to "$(inherited)"